# How do I represent Python's typing.Any in Java?

Tags: java, python, parsing, intellij-plugin

I am working on a Java project and I want to parse some Python code using Java.

The Python code contains some types from the **typing** module in Python. Based on certain types I need to run specific methods so how can I represent Python types which do not exist within Java. One example for such a type is `typing.Any`.

For `typing.Any` is it equivalent to use Java generics? Would I just need to look through the source code of a particular python type and then reimplement it in Java or is there any other way to do this?

From what I understand the `typing.Any` class in Python just disables any type checking and I do not understand how to do that in Java. Currently I am using Java Object but I know that Object is not the right representation of Any.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Seems like having the type be `Object` would be equivalent, any reason you can think of why it's not?

Comment: Assuming you don't mind boxing for primitives, `Object` is a superclass of all types in java.

Comment: *No* Python types exist in Java. They're Python types. Java doesn't have them. Java may have vaguely similar types, but they all have different semantics and supported operations.

Comment: @RandomDavis no, it isn't. There's a reason you don't just use `object` in Python. `Any` is basically an "escape valve" from the typing system. For example, `def foo(x: Any): return x.some_method()` would pass type checking, but `def foo(x: object): return x.some_method()` would not

Comment: In any case, you *really* shouldn't be trying to transliterate code. Instead, understand what the code does in Python, then write that same algorithm in Java.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga don't you mean you _shouldn't_ be trying to transliterate?

Comment: Are you looking for the standard Java type that is *most vaguely similar* to `typing.Any`, or do you actually want to represent `typing.Any`? Can you elaborate on "Based on certain types I need to run specific methods"? What properties do you actually need here?

Answer (score 1):

> disables any type checking and I do not understand how to do that in Java.

In java, the language, you can't do that. Java doesn't let you opt out of type safety.

> For typing.Any is it equivalent to use Java generics?

No.

> is there any other way to do this?

`Object` covers all you need here.

```
Object o = (whatever python gave you);
```

Of course, because java is strongly typed, you can't just call methods on `o` and have the compiler go: Well, uh, okay then, I guess if we get lucky and that method so happens to be there at runtime I'll call it, and if not, uh.. I'll throw an exception I guess.

That's not how java works. There is nothing you can do to make java work like that. All that java will let you do with your `o` reference is things that are guaranteed to work on any and all objects (which isn't much)!

What you can use is reflection, but note that the method name isn't sufficient, unless there is only one method with that name (in java, you can have different methods that have the same name, so long as their param types differ). This is extremely unwieldy, but is possible:

```
Object o = (get from python);
String methodName = "sayHello";
Method m = findMethodWithName(o, methodName);
Object[] args = new Object[] {"Joe"};
m.invoke(o, args);
```

with:

```
Method findMethodWithName(Object o, String name) {
  Method candidate = null;
  for (Method m : o.getClass().getMethods()) {
    if (!m.getName().equals(name)) continue;
    if (candidate != null) {
      throw new NoSuchMethodException("more than one " + name + " in " + o.getClass());
    }
    candidate = m;
  }
  if (candidate == null) throw new NoSuchMethodException("no public " + name + " in " + o.getClass());
  return candidate;
}
```

This is dog slow, of course. If you like this sort of thing, java isn't what you're looking for. Maybe groovy.